# how to iterare over list of words?

Tags: python

I have a regular expression to find a specific word and the filters some text.

But now I want to iterate over a list of words and filter then some text.

So this is my regular expression:

```
def regex_fruit_cost(subst):
    return r"(?<=" + subst + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"
```

and this is my list of words:

```
fruit_words = ['Appels', 'Ananas', 'Peen Waspeen',
               'Tomaten Cherry', 'Sinaasappels',
               'Watermeloenen', 'Rettich', 'Peren', 'Peen', 'Mandarijnen', 'Meloenen', 'Grapefruit']
```

and the text for filtering the words from it:

```
text t.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.\n\nrut ard wegetables\n\x0c']"
```

Combine it:

```
regex = r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(" + '|'.join(re.escape(word)
                                             for word in fruit_words) + ')'
fruit_cost_found = re.findall(regex_fruit_cost('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in fruit_words)), text)
print(*fruit_cost_found, sep='\n')
```

But then I get this 'strange error':

```
raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Question: what I have to change that it can iterate over the list of words?

so in the text you will find:

Watermeloenen, Appels. So the regular expression works for a single word. For example Watermeloenen. And then it returns this list:

```
123,20
2.772,00
46,20
577,50
69,30
```

But now I want to have all the numbers for all the fruit words.

I try it like this:

```
single_fruit = [fruit for fruit in  fruit_words]
fruit_cost_found = re.findall(regex_fruit_cost(single_fruit), text)
```

error:

```
return r"(?<=" + subst + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`single_fruit` in your code is a list. You need to iterate over its elements to be able to use in in `re.findall` as it requires a string:

```
fruit_cost_found = []

for fruit in single_fruit:
    m = re.findall(regex_fruit_cost(fruit), text)
    if m:
        fruit_cost_found.append(m)

fruit_cost_found = [item for sublist in fruit_cost_found for item in sublist]

['3.488,16', '137,50', '500,00', '1.000,00', '2.000,00', '1.000,00', '381,25', '123,20', '2.772,00', '46,20', '577,50', '69,30']
```

Comment: #Anoushiravan R  But it calls now two times  re.findall(regex_fruit_cost(fruit), text). this is not so sufficient

Comment: You are right. Check my edited answer please.

Comment: eh, yes, oke. and then also the declaration of  single_fruit = [fruit for fruit in fruit_words]

Comment: What do you mean by sufficient?

Comment: #Anoushiravan R So if it founds a word in the fruit list it will be added to the empty list. But then it reads the whole file again from the beginning searching for another word in the fruit list?

Comment: Well you are looking for some specific words in your text file. It's normal to start from the beginning for new words. I also put an if clause in between so that if there is no match it appends nothing to the list.

Comment: #Anoushiravan R Hi R. But now it prints the values from less occurence to more occurence: [['3.488,16'], ['137,50', '500,00', '1.000,00', '2.000,00', '1.000,00', '381,25'], ['123,20', '2.772,00', '46,20', '577,50', '69,30']]. But it has to be from just occurence in the textfield. So it begins with: 123.20 and ends with 381.25

Comment: It finds them based on the order of words in single fruit. If you had a specific output in mind you should have specified it in the question. So what it does now is it looks for a specific word in the text and if it could find a match it will append the corresponding values on the empty list.